# How do I remove empty dataframes from a sequence of dataframes in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How do I remove empty data frames from a sequence of data frames? In this below code snippet, there are many empty data frames in twoColDF. Also another question for the below for loop, is there a way that I can make this efficient? I tried rewriting this to below line but didn't work

```
//finalDF2 = (1 until colCount).flatMap(j => groupCount(j).map( y=> finalDF.map(a=>a.filter(df(cols(j)) === y)))).toSeq.flatten

   var twoColDF: Seq[Seq[DataFrame]] = null
if (colCount == 2  ) 
{
  val i = 0
  for (j <- i + 1 until colCount) {

      twoColDF = groupCount(j).map(y => {
      finalDF.map(x => x.filter(df(cols(j)) === y))

    })

  }
}finalDF = twoColDF.flatten
```

Comment: your question is hard to understand: what's the type of `finalDF`? And what's `groupCount`?

Answer (score 1):

Given a set of DataFrames, you can access each DataFrame's underlying RDD and use `isEmpty` to filter out the empty ones:

```
val input: Seq[DataFrame] = ???
val result = input.filter(!_.rdd.isEmpty())
```

As for your other question - I can't understand what your code tries to do, but I'd first try to convert it into something more *functional* (remove use of `var`s and imperative conditionals). If I'm **guessing** the meaning of your inputs, here's something that might be equivalent to what you're trying to do:

```
var input: Seq[DataFrame] = ???

// map of column index to column values -
// for each combination we'd want a new DF where that column has that value
// I'm assuming values are Strings, can be anything else
val groupCount: Map[Int, Seq[String]] = ???

// for each combination of DF + column + value - produce the filtered DF where this column has this value
val perValue: Seq[DataFrame] = for {
  df <- input
  index <- groupCount.keySet
  value <- groupCount(index)
} yield df.filter(col(df.columns(index)) === value)

// remove empty results:
val result: Seq[DataFrame] = perValue.filter(!_.rdd.isEmpty())
```